# canonical-livepatch, Doesn't seem to patch anything

Tags: 18.04, canonical-livepatch

When I ssh into the server it says:

```
11 packages can be updated.
11 updates are security updates.
```

Then I verify that everything is installed:

```
canonical-livepatch status --verbose
```

And this is what I get:

```
client-version: 9.3.0
machine-id: xxx
machine-token: xxx
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1246 v3 @ 3.50GHz
last-check: 2019-05-15T18:08:12Z
boot-time: 2019-05-11T10:06:52Z
uptime: 104h34m56s
status:
- kernel: 4.15.0-48.51-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    checkState: checked
    patchState: nothing-to-apply
    version: ""
    fixes: ""
```

So there is nothing to apply? How about those 11 security updates then?

UPDATE:

As requested this is the list of upgradeable:

```
apt list --upgradable



intel-microcode/bionic-security,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security 3.20190514.0ubuntu0.18.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.20180807a.0ubuntu0.18.04.1]
libwbclient0/bionic-security,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.10 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9]
linux-generic/bionic-security,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0.50.52 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.48.50]
linux-headers-generic/bionic-security,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0.50.52 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.48.50]
linux-image-generic/bionic-security,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0.50.52 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0.48.50]
linux-libc-dev/bionic-security,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security 4.15.0-50.54 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.15.0-48.51]
python3-distupgrade/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-updates 1:18.04.32 all [upgradable from: 1:18.04.31]
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-updates 1:18.04.32 all [upgradable from: 1:18.04.31]
```

Comment: If you want to automatically install packages via `apt` you just need to run `sudo apt install unattended-upgrades` and then `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades` to configure it to your liking. The "canonical-livepatch" is about fixing critical bugs in currently running Linux kernel image without restarting the kernel (that is, rebooting the system). However, to my knowlege, Canonical has never released any livepatch.

Answer (score 1):

[Does any of those 11 updates qualify?](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/10/canonical-livepatch.html). If so file a bug report if they have not updated.

> **Q: What kinds of updates will be provided by the Canonical Livepatch Service?**
>
> A: The [Canonical Livepatch Service](https://www.ubuntu.com/livepatch) is intended to address high and critical severity Linux kernel security vulnerabilities, as identified by Ubuntu Security Notices and the [CVE database](https://cve.mitre.org/). Note that there are some limitations to the kernel livepatch technology -- some Linux kernel code paths cannot be safely patched while running. We will do our best to supply Canonical Livepatches for high and critical vulnerabilities in a timely fashion whenever possible. There may be occasions when the traditional kernel upgrade and reboot might still be necessary. We’ll communicate that clearly through the usual mechanisms -- USNs, Landscape, Desktop Notifications, Byobu, /etc/motd, etc.

[From the USN mailing list](https://usn.ubuntu.com/) I would expect...

- [USN-3981-2](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3981-2/): Linux kernel (HWE) vulnerabilities. 15.5.
- [USN-3980-2](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3980-2/): Linux kernel (HWE) vulnerabilities. 15.5.
- [USN-3981-1](https://usn.ubuntu.com/3981-1/): Linux kernel vulnerabilities. 14.5.

to quality (the others are not marked as 18.04). As you only listed "11 updates": Have you had these installed on your server? Can you confirm if they are?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have added it to my question. Not quite sure. But it seems these are not listed. Which means they have been updated?

Comment: I went through all my system logs (since September 2019 I activated the livepatch feature) and it seems that Canonical hasn't released any livepatches at least since that. I did find lots of miscellaneous errors with the service, though, which doesn't raise confidence in the implementation quality. Do you know if Canonical has *ever* released any livepatches in reality?

Comment: Reading through the marketing material suggests that livepatch is only supported with `generic` kernel image. I'm using `lowlatency-hwe` kernel and that's not going to get any updates ever. I'm removing the livepatch feature from my systems and just keep rebooting.

Comment: Livepatch never installs or upgrades packages, it only applies hotfixes to running kernels