# How to configure unattended-upgrades with Canonical Livepatch

Tags: unattended-upgrades, canonical-livepatch

I am using unattended-upgrades on my server for keeping it up-to-date.
I have also tried to enable Canonical Livepatch for avoiding to restart the system.

It seems that unattended-upgrades updates the kernel before Livepatch patches it.

Do I need to configure unattended-upgrades differently when running it together with Livepatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked something similar a while ago, which was redirected to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143535/canonical-livepatch-doesnt-seem-to-patch-anything).

But to elaborate, no you don't have to configure anything differently, because unattended-upgrades and livepatch works in different ways.

- unattended-upgrades runs once per day, and by default includes security updates, including kernel updates which can't be livepatched.
- livepatch runs periodically (multiple times per day), and only patches critical and high-risk kernel vulnerabilities.

It's actually quite few kernel vulnerabilites that are livepatched - in a 6-month timespan, I think there has only been 2 or 3 livepatches for 20.04 (kernel 5.4.0-xx).

So livepatches are actually rare occurences, where regular kernel updates are much more common - which still requires a reboot.

Hope that helps.